# Bits representation of number String vs Integer in Java

Tags: java, ascii, bit

Bit representation of "12" that is String is "00110001 00110010" where "00110001" represents ASCII value 49 that is for "1" and "00110010" represents ASCII value 50 that is "2".
This looks good for String but how integer value of 12 will be converted to bits in Java?
If both of them will be the same then how Java will determine whether its data type after reaching target after serialization?

Comment: *but how integer value of 12 will be converted to bits in Java?* That would be 1100 in binary. As for serialization, if you're talking about serialization as it occurs particularly in Java, you're thinking at too low a level. It doesn't happen bits-wise, it happens through construction of objects and saving into a special 'binary' (NOT in the 'bits-sense') format

Comment: @g00se But in ASCII 12 represent Form Feed character. How java will differentiate whether it is integer 12 or form feed character?

Comment: You should not be using `char c = 12`if you are trying to store integers

Comment: Is this question out of curiosity for how data is represented or to solve a problem you are facing?

Comment: By context. A form feed character would have to be used in a `char` or `Character` context. Perhaps `String` in certain cases, but not so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Object Serialization differentiates between an integer 12 and a String containing a `(char)12` by writing additional metadata.

For example, here is [ObjectOutputStream.writeString](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/64cc2bc73816f3e0a91776805482fee37fa37bbe/jdk/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#L1301). As you can see, it writes a constant byte `TC_STRING` (which happens to be defined as `(byte)0x74`) to signal that the data that follows is a String:

```
private void writeString(String str, boolean unshared) throws IOException {
    handles.assign(unshared ? null : str);
    long utflen = bout.getUTFLength(str);
    if (utflen <= 0xFFFF) {
        bout.writeByte(TC_STRING);
        bout.writeUTF(str, utflen);
    } else {
        bout.writeByte(TC_LONGSTRING);
        bout.writeLongUTF(str, utflen);
    }
}
```

The reader can then read one byte, check if it's TC_STRING, and if so, it knows that the following data is a String, and not an integer or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Integers aren't ASCII. The actual characters of the number aren't stored anywhere

`int x = 12` would be the same as `int x = 0b1100`

Unclear what serialization format you're referring to (but, Protobuf, for example, would be better than Java default ObjectInputStream) or what specific error you're having. The serialization framework itself should encode field boundaries at bit positions, for example - https://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html

Answer (score 0):

ASCII [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) a *character* encoding standard, which maps **characters** to the code-points.

`'1'` is a character, `'2'` is a character, `'a'` is a character, `'?'` is also a character..

`12`, however, is a number, that is *not* mapped to any code-point.

You can convert an integer to its binary string representation as:

```java
int x = 12;
String bx = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
```

and

```java
System.out.println(bx);
```

will print `1100`, which is `12` in decimal system.

Comment: Int should store in bytes right, example 12 should take a byte which should look like - 00001100  and when we store 129 it should take 2 bytes right but it shows as 1000001, doesn't show 2 bytes.